# Worksheet_Change crashes after looping for less than 300 rows

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop

The goal is for the cells in Sheet1 that have the same previous column as the cells in Sheet2 to update each time we make a change (and vice versa).

In a smaller Excel workbook the code was working but in the actual Excel workbook I want to update it is crashing Excel with the error:

> -2147417848 (80010108): Method 'Value' of Object 'Range' Failed.

The code for Sheet1

````vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim counter As Integer
    For counter = 10 To 290
        If Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(counter, 6).Value = Target.Offset(0, -1).Value Then
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(counter, 7).Value = Target.Value
        End If
    Next counter
End Sub```
````

The code for Sheet2:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim counter As Integer
    For counter = 19 To 66
        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter, 6).Value = Target.Offset(0, -1).Value Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter, 7).Value = Target.Value
        End If
    Next counter
End Sub
```

Comment: `Target.Offset(0, -1)` - if you make a change in ColA then you can't refer one column to the left of that...

Comment: @TimWilliams the change is being done on the G column and it's checking if the values on the F column are the same as the ones on the other sheet

Comment: What's the value of `counter` when it fails? When updating a sheet with a `Change` event handler, it's a good idea to first disable events, so you don't keep triggering the change over and over. Don't forget to re-enable events when done.

Comment: Also add a line to exit sub when `Target.CountLarge > 1` since the rest of your code can only handle single-cell `Target` ranges.

Comment: I test your code with 10 to 290 counter, it doesn't throw me an error. So I have "A" in sheet1 cell F10. And in sheet2, I have "A" from cell F10 to F290. In sheet1, I type "7" in cell G10. The sheet_change give result in sheet2, cell G10 to G290 value is "7". Your code is saying something like this, whenever a user type something in a cell within column G10:G290, get the value of that cell.offset(0,-1) -say, the value is A and user type 7 in G10- , then to each cell in sheet2 range F10:F290, if the value is "A" then fill next column with 7. Please CMIIW.

Comment: You wrote _the change is being done on the G_ ... I think you'd better restrict the target column to avoid error if the user change a cell value other than in column G. And better, use the intersect to fire the change event. For example : _if the cell which value changed is within cell G10:G290 then do ...._

Comment: Also, I think it's better like this `if sheets("Sheet2").cells(counter, 6).value = target.offset(0,-1).value then`

Comment: @karma yes, the behavior of the cell you mentioned is correct. So if in sheet 1 cell G290 I type 7 and the value of F290 is the same as some cell in F10:F290 (let's say it's F200) in sheet2, the cell G200 in sheet 2 will update to 7

Comment: I made some changes to the sub as @karma mentioned (add .value on the if statement and change the order for the comparison (it's working for a range of 500 which is enough for me)
I made the same changes to the sub that is referring to sheet1 (so that when values change in sheet2 they are updated in sheet1) and now that one is breaking which is weird because it has even less cells (the range to look for the values in F is around 50)

Comment: Please if you don't mind, put both sub in your question. Probably you forget to change the name of the sheet. In sheet2 module, it should be like this : `if sheets("Sheet1").cells(counter, 6).value = target.offset(0,-1).value then`. And maybe it's better to put `application.enableevents=false`

Comment: It seems you need to put 'application.enableevents=false`. Because both sheet module has the change_event, so it will trigger the sub in the other modul if condition meet.

Comment: Where can I put that the application.enableevents=false? before the for loop? or during the if condition?
Also, I will need to set it to true at the end of each sub no?

Comment: Please have a look to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rg As Range: Dim counter As Integer
Application.EnableEvents = False
Set rg = Range("G10:G290")
    If Not Intersect(Target, rg) Is Nothing Then
        For counter = 10 To 290
            If Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(counter, 6).Value = Target.Offset(0, -1).Value Then
                Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(counter, 7).Value = Target.Value
            End If
        Next
    End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

the rg is to restrict the area of the cell which is changed.
So, if the cell changed is outside G10:G290, it won't trigger the loop.

And it should have the `application.enableevents=false` in the beginning and set it back to true ---> `application.enableevents=true` just before the end sub to avoid the sheet_change sub in another sheet module is triggered.

FYI, this kind of code will work something like this :
Say, in **sheet1 and sheeet2** cell F15,F20 and F25 value is "A".
And in **sheet1 and sheeet2** cell G15 value = 1, G20 = 2, G25 = 3.

In sheet1 cell G20, a user type 7.
Result in sheet2 cell G15, G20 and G25 value is 7, 
**but** in sheet1 cell G15 value is still 1 and cell G25 value is still 3.

Later on, another user type 100 in sheet2 cell G25.
Result in sheet1 cell G15, G20 and G25 value is 100, 
**but** in sheet2 cell G15 and cell G20 value is still 7.

Is that your expected result ?

Comment: Hi, yes that's the expected result. And the subs are working now. Thank you so much!